# How to query the customfield in the OpportunityProduct by apex?

Tags: trigger, opportunity-lineitem, quotelineitem

to all Now I am trying to the update trigger the concept of this trigger is if I written something in the QuoteLineItemTextArea__c in the custom field from the quoteLineItem in the opportunity is updated the same  opportunity in opportunityProduct having the custom field named OpportunityProducttextArea__c (condition in quote and opportunity in sync only).
So I have written the code followingly, here I have done the half of the code.I only known to the querying quoteline item only

> so I want to know how to query the custom field OpportunityProducttextArea__c
>   in the opportunityProduct

My trigger code:

```
public class CustomSyncHandler {
    public static void UpdateTrigger (List<QuoteLineItem> InsertedQuote) {

        Set<Id> setofProductId = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setofQuoteId = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setofOpportunityId = new Set<Id>();

      for(QuoteLineItem RecordQuoteItem: InsertedQuote){
          //QuoteDetail.get(RecordQuoteItem.QuoteId);//Try to get quote here 
          setofProductId.add(RecordQuoteItem.Product2Id);
          setofQuoteId.add(RecordQuoteItem.QuoteId);

      }
      system.debug('@@@ setofProductId is'+ setofProductId);
      system.debug('@@@ setofQuoteId is'+ setofQuoteId);

       List<Quote> QuoteList = new List<Quote>();

       QuoteList = [SELECT Id,Name,OpportunityId, IsSyncing FROM Quote Where Id IN:setofQuoteId ];

       for (Quote quoteitem: QuoteList){
           If(quoteitem.IsSyncing == True){
           setofOpportunityId.add(quoteitem.OpportunityId);
           }
       }
       system.debug('@@@ setofOpportunityId is'+setofOpportunityId);


       Map<Id,Opportunity> = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name, OpportunityProducttextArea__c FROM OpportunityProduct])

    }
}
```

here My plan is,If i query that opportunityproduct customfield,

I check the quote is synced to that opportunity then

If quotelineitem in the opportunity's id and the opportunityproduct in the opportunity's id are same then I try to provide update the data from the quoteline item custom field to the opportunityproduct custom field

Comment: `OpportunityProduct` is available as `OpportunityLineItem`. So perform query on that.Your query should be something like this: `SELECT Id, Name, OpportunityProducttextArea__c FROM OpportunityLineItem`

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Thanks a lot it's very help ful for my issue

Comment: can i post this as an answer, if it solved your issue?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo No actually I done the query followingly, but it's give empty result can you tell tha t what is the error in this query,  Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> OppoLineItemMap = new Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Id, Name, OpportunityProducttextArea__c, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id IN:setofOpportunityId]);

Comment: `setofOpportunityId` is set of `opportunityId`, not the set of OpportunityLineItem id.Replace `Id` with `opportunityId` and try again

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I have know the OpportunityLineitem having the one of the field in opportunityId in the following link [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.ja-jp.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm].so I try to separete another opportunityline items using the opportunityid in my above posted query.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo it's also give empty Map as aresult of my query now like this followingly,        Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> OppoLineItemMap = new Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT  Name, OpportunityProducttextArea__c, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id IN:setofOpportunityId]);
is it wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48106/discussion-between-mohanraj-and-mr-frodo).

Comment: Yes it is wrong. You are putting where clause on wrong object's Id.You have to replace that with OpportunityId.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I replace the Id with opportunityId in where clause that's also provide the same result.my new query I provide  in the chat.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Can you please post your answer it's help to done the task for me so it's may be useful for others as selected as a best answer. :D

Comment: Sounds great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points which were helpful for you in solving the problem...

1. Opportunity Product is the object which shows list of Products related to an opportunity. We refer it as [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm) in code.
2. Filter in `WHERE` clause refers to the wrong set of records. Replacing `Id` with `OpportunityId` could be helpful.